# Improving python code for updating google spreadsheets

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets, xlsx, xls

First of all, I am new to python (practically I have learned only from Sololearn,  that too only up to half course). So I request you to give me a little bit detailed answer.
My task has following broad steps:-

1. Delete old .xlsx file(if any)
2. Convert two .xls files into .xlsx file using win32, delete the first row and then delete .xls file [weird xls files already downloaded into source directory + xlrd,pyexcel show error (unsupported format or corrupt) file in opening .xls file (online analysis of file predicts it to be html/htm) ]
3. Get data from xlsx file
4. First, delete old worksheet on google spreadsheet to remove old data. Create a new worksheet with the same name. Insert data into new worksheet on the google spreadsheet.
5. Open second sheet(which imports data from the first sheet) and update one cell in Dummy Sheet to make sure google spreadsheet is synchronised in the background.

Now, I wrote a code by combining many codes and by using a lot of google.
The code is working fine but it takes on an avg about 65 seconds to complete the whole process.
My question has 3 parts:-

1. Is there any way to directly access data from .xls file?
2. Is there any way this code's performance can be improved.
3. Any other more efficient method for completing the above-said task?

My Code:-

```
import time
import win32com.client as win32
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

start = time.time()

# set input-output file locations
source_dir = "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Downloads"
output_dir = "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Excels"

# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
# make sure to share files with email contained in json file
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
# code will not work without json file
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\your.json", scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
# following code is to open any spreadsheet by name
sh = gc.open("First Sheet")

def save_as_xlsx(input_file,output_dir,output_file_name) :
              # call excel using win32, then open .xls file
              # delete first row and then save as .xlsx
              excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
              wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(input_file)
              wbk = excel.ActiveWorkbook 
              sheet = wbk.Sheets(1) 
              sheet.Rows(1).Delete()
              wb.SaveAs(output_dir + '\\' + output_file_name, FileFormat = 51)
              #FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension. FileFormat = 56 is for .xls extension
              wb.Close()
              excel.Application.Quit()
              return True

def get_the_data_from_xlsx(output_dir,output_file_name) :
              # use openpyxl.load to find out last cell of file
              # store cell values in list called data
              wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(output_dir + '\\' + output_file_name)
              sheet = wb.active
              max_row_no = sheet.max_row
              max_column_no = sheet.max_column
              max_column = get_column_letter(max_column_no)
              last_cell = str(max_column) + str(max_row_no)
              cell_addresses = sheet['A1' : last_cell]
              data = []
              for i in cell_addresses :
                  for e in i :
                      data.append(e.value)
              return (data,last_cell)

def insert_data_into_spreadsheet(name_of_worksheet,data,last_cell) :
              # Find a workbook by name in already opened spreadsheet
              # delete the worksheet to clear old data
              # create worksheet with same name to maintain import connections in sheets.
              worksheet = sh.worksheet(name_of_worksheet)
              sh.del_worksheet(worksheet)
              worksheet = sh.add_worksheet(title=name_of_worksheet, rows="500", cols="30")
              # store range of cells for spreadsheet in list named cell_list
              cell_list = worksheet.range('A1' + ':' + str(last_cell))
              # attach all the values from data list as per the cell_list
              a = 0
              for cell in cell_list :
                  cell.value = data[a]
                  a = a + 1
              # update all cells stored in cell_list in one go       
              worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)

def delete_file(directory,file_initials) :
       for filename in os.listdir(directory) :
              if filename.startswith(file_initials) :
                     os.unlink(directory  +"\\" +  filename)

# check if files are in source_dir
for filename in os.listdir(source_dir) :
       # check for file1.xls and set input_file name if any file exists.
       if filename.startswith("file1"):
              input_file = source_dir + "\\file1.xls"
              output_file1 = "output_file1.xlsx"
              # detect and delete any old file in output directory
              delete_file(output_dir,"output_file1")

              if save_as_xlsx(input_file,output_dir,output_file1) == True :       
                     # delete the file from source directory after work is done
                     delete_file(source_dir,'file1')

              # get data from new xlsx file
              data_from_xlsx = get_the_data_from_xlsx(output_dir,output_file1)
              data_to_spreadsheet = data_from_xlsx[0]
              last_cell = data_from_xlsx[1]

              # insert updated data into spreadsheet
              insert_data_into_spreadsheet("file1_data",data_to_spreadsheet,last_cell)           

       # repeat the same process for 2nd file
       if filename.startswith('file2'):
              input_file = source_dir + "\\file2.xls"
              output_file2 = "output_file2.xlsx"

              delete_file(output_dir,"output_file2")

              if save_as_xlsx(input_file,output_dir,output_file2) == True :
                     delete_file(source_dir,'file2')

              data_from_xlsx = get_the_data_from_xlsx(output_dir,output_file2)
              data_to_spreadsheet = data_from_xlsx[0]
              last_cell = data_from_xlsx[1]

              insert_data_into_spreadsheet("file2_data",data_to_spreadsheet,last_cell)           

# open spreadsheet by name and open Dummy worksheet
# update one cell to sync the sheet with other sheets
sh = gc.open("second sheet")
worksheet = sh.worksheet("Dummy")
worksheet.update_acell('B1', '=Today()')

end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```